# Grouping Trig Terms

Tags: trigonometry

I'm confused as to how the $\cos^2\theta$$\cos^2\phi$ + $\cos^2\theta$$\sin^2\phi$ simplifies to $\cos^2\theta$ and likewise for the $phi^2 d/dx$ part also. Did I miss something in double angle calc?

[image]

Comment: No double angles, just algebra, $\cos^2\theta(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, $$\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi+\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi=\cos^2\theta(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)=\cos^2\theta(1)=\cos^2\theta.$$

Similarly for the second, $$16\theta^2\cos^2\theta+16\phi^2\sin^2\theta+16\theta^2\sin^2\theta = 16(\theta^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)+\phi^2\sin^2\theta)=16(\theta^2+\phi^2\sin^2\theta).$$

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh ridiculous, I overcomplicated things.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos^2\theta. \cos^2\phi + \cos^2\theta. \sin^2\phi = \cos^2\theta.(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi) = \cos^2\theta$$

$$16\theta^2\cos^2\theta+16\phi^2\sin^2\theta+16\theta^2\sin^2\theta = 16(\theta^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)+\phi^2\sin^2\theta)=16(\theta^2+\phi^2\sin^2\theta)$$